# How to sort recordstore records based on a certain field in it?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

For example there are three records in a recordstore , and the structure of a record in the recordstore is like this : `lastname;firstname;moneyborrowed`

I want to show these three records inside a LWUIT Table and I want them to be sorted by the lastname column. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

save using

```
Preferences preferences = new Preferences("mydbname");
preferences.put("key","lastname;firstname;moneyborrowed");
preferences.save();
```

and retrieve using

```
String val = (string) preferences.get("key");
```

**Preferences.java**

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.microedition.rms.RecordEnumeration;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStoreException;

public class Preferences {
    private final String mRecordStoreName;

    private final Hashtable mHashtable;

    public Preferences(String recordStoreName)
    throws RecordStoreException {
        mRecordStoreName = recordStoreName;
        mHashtable = new Hashtable();
        load();
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return (String)mHashtable.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        if (value == null) value = "";
        mHashtable.put(key, value);
    }

    private void load() throws RecordStoreException {
        RecordStore rs = null;
        RecordEnumeration re = null;

        try {
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(mRecordStoreName, true);
            re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
            while (re.hasNextElement()) {
                byte[] raw = re.nextRecord();
                String pref = new String(raw);
                // Parse out the name.
                int index = pref.indexOf('|');
                String name = pref.substring(0, index);
                String value = pref.substring(index + 1);
                put(name, value);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (re != null) re.destroy();
            if (rs != null) rs.closeRecordStore();
        }
    }

    public void save() throws RecordStoreException {
        RecordStore rs = null;
        RecordEnumeration re = null;
        try {
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(mRecordStoreName, true);
            re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);

            // First remove all records, a little clumsy.
            while (re.hasNextElement()) {
                int id = re.nextRecordId();
                rs.deleteRecord(id);
            }

            // Now save the preferences records.
            Enumeration keys = mHashtable.keys();
            while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
                String value = get(key);
                String pref = key + "|" + value;
                byte[] raw = pref.getBytes();
                rs.addRecord(raw, 0, raw.length);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (re != null) re.destroy();
            if (rs != null) rs.closeRecordStore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok , I implemented the RecordComparator interface and in the compare method I implemented the comparison rule. So when calling the enumerateRecords I passed the RecordComparator object as its parameter. And the resultset is sorted !