# sms receive form

Tags: java, java-me, sms, lwuit

I wanna display the message sent from wma console in LWUIT form...
The sms are stored in record ... and I need to get the sms from the record ..
I have stored the sms in record but having problem in retrieving it and displaying

```
if (ae.getSource()==inboxlist){
    iform = new Form("Message");


        try {
                record = RecordStore.openRecordStore("Sms", true );
            s = new String(record.getRecord(smsindex));

              inb = new Label();
        inb.setText(s);

        } catch (RecordStoreException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      iform.addComponent(inb);
    iform.addCommand(exit);
    iform.setCommandListener(this);
          iform.show();
}
```

Comment: Also, this question seems unclear to me.  What problem are you having specifically, i.e. what behaviour are you *seeing* and what behaviour did you *expect* or want?

Answer (score 1):

see my answer at

[How to sort recordstore records based on a certain field in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573286/how-to-sort-recordstore-records-based-on-a-certain-field-in-it/6578002#6578002)

use preferance class as it used to save sms